# How to use fx autocomplete in Excel w/o mouse

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, autocomplete

When you type a formula into Excel 2007, it brings up hints for functions. For example, type `=L` into the *f*x field and a bunch of functions will appear in a drop down menu (Large, LCM, Left, etc).

Using the up and down keys, you can select a function. **But I cannot figure out how to select that function without using the mouse!** The enter key, space bar, insert key all don't work. But double clicking the function will place it into the formula bar. Is there a key to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the function you want using the arrow keys as your doing now, then **press the TAB key** to auto-complete to that function.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! :)

Comment: Zoran! You saved a couple of years for me!))